# Partial Integration Expression

Tags: integration

Which variable set as U and DV and whats DU and V to replace into the formula?
$$\int \frac{x^n dx} {\sqrt{x^2+a}}$$
I think it is an exponential seperation question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}=x^n$ and $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}$. If you take them the other way around you end up with a horrible integral. Using the above substitutions, you end up with some quite nice cancelling